# DataFrame agg as a series

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to convert the output of DataFrame.agg to a series where the index is a combination of column name and agg function name.

See I have

```
In [132]: df = pd.DataFrame({ 
     ...:     col: np.random.rand(5) for col in 'abc' 
     ...: })                                                                              

In [133]: out = df.agg(['sum', 'min', 'max'])                                             

In [134]: out                                                                             
Out[134]: 
            a         b         c
sum  2.898835  2.767717  2.270150
min  0.234784  0.492247  0.164680
max  0.913080  0.678060  0.773441
```

Out like to convert the output to a series with index like: `a_sum, a_min, a_max, b_sum, b_min, b_max ...`

I've looked at `pivot` but I can't figure out how make it do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack or melt the data and join index

```
out = out.T.stack()
out.index = out.index.map('_'.join)

a_sum    1.258670
a_min    0.022124
a_max    0.758263
b_sum    2.661875
b_min    0.273627
b_max    0.770407
c_sum    2.833126
c_min    0.163624
c_max    0.997125
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I do it with melt?

Comment: @lazy1, can be done with melt but stack is more straight-forward

Answer (score 0):

Since OP asked, here is one way to do it with `melt`:

```
from itertools import product

ind = [''.join([x[1], '_', x[0]]) for x in list(product(list(out), out.index.tolist()))]
out = out.melt()
out.variable = ind
```